# Model-to-Model-Transformation - no meta model for source

Tags: eclipse, uml, modeling

I have to do a model-to-model transformation but the source model is rather obscure but also quite similar to UML activity diagrams (which are also the target by the way).

I've looked into tutorials for Eclipse Modeling Tools but I struggle a lot with it. Also, because there is no meta model for the source, I'm not sure if EMT is any help. What are my options here? Can I use EMT, should I use another tool in this case or should I write a generator myself?

Greetings

Comment: When you say, model-to-model, I assume you have a e.g. UML Class Model that you want to transform to e.g. ERD. However, you appear to be also wanting to build an initial model using source code? You could use Sparx EA to reverse-engineer the code into a model and then transform that? Is this what you mean?

Comment: What tool produced your source model ?